# Let $f$ be a monotone function such that $\lim_{n\to+\infty} f\left(\frac1n\right)=1$. So $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0^+} f(h)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

> Let $f$ be a monotone function such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty} f\left(\frac1n\right)=1$. So $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0^+} f(h)=1$.

I see:

Say that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty} f\left(\frac1n\right)=1$ is the same as, after a certain order $f\left(\frac 1n\right)\in]1-l,1+l[$. As $f$ is monotonous, suppose increasing, for $x<\frac 1n$,
$1<f(x)<f\left(\frac 1n\right)<1+l$, so $\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0^+} f(h)=1$. But this does not seem clear enough to me.
Could you help me to make the demonstration clearer (mainly because $1<f(x)$.) and more complete, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon >0$ and suppose WLOG that $f$ is increasing. Since $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(1/n)= 1,$$  there is $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $$\forall n\in\mathbb N,n\geq N\implies 1-\varepsilon <f(1/n)<1+\varepsilon .$$ Set $\delta=\frac{1}{N}$. Then, if $0<h<\delta =\frac{1}{N}$, using the fact that $f$ is increasing yields
$$1-\varepsilon <1\leq f(h)<f(1/N)<1+\varepsilon,$$
and thus $$|f(h)-1|<\varepsilon ,$$
whenver $0<h<\delta $. Therefore $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}f(h)=1.$$

---

**The proof that $f(h)\geq1$ for all $h>0$.**

First of all, since $f$ increasing, the sequence $x_n:=f(1/n)$ is decreasing. Since $x_n\to 1$ whenever $n\to \infty $, you have that $x_n\geq 1$ for all $n$. Let $h>0$. Let $m$ big enough so that $0<\frac{1}{m}<h$. Since $f$ is increasing, $$f(h)\geq f(1/m)=x_m\geq 1.$$
Since $h>0$ is unspecified, you get $f(h)\geq 1$ for all $h>0$.